# How to update json parameters dynamically

Tags: json, unix, curl, awk, sed

i have a file workflow.log in json format.I want to update the json file with updated values with the parameters supplied during runtime.for e.g i want to update 'XXXXXX' with some value passed through param like 'ZZZZZZZ'. I have created the shell script storing the content of the file in a variable called WKFL_DET and using it in a curl command. Now i am not sure how to proceed further to make use of variables  $p_id and $p_file_name.

workflow.log

```
 "Workparams": [
        {
          "$id": "12",
          "WorkflowParmId": 84232,
          "WorkflowId": 9766,
          "Name": "SYS_FILE_DT",
          "Value": "2018-09-28"
        },
        {
          "$id": "13",
          "WorkflowParmId": 221910,
          "WorkflowId": 9766,
          "Name": "V_FILE_NAME",
          "Value": "XXXXXX"
        },
        {
          "$id": "14",
          "WorkflowParmId": 221908,
          "WorkflowId": 9766,
          "Name": "V_ID",
          "Value": "1111"
        }
```

curl.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh   
    export p_id=$1
    export p_file_name=$2
    function func
{   
    WKFL_DET=`cat ${workflow.log}`

     curl -X PUT -H '"$HEADER_ACCEPT"' -H ${HEADER_JSON_CONTENT} -H Authorization:'Bearer AAEAAJ038MNIYpxfgQvsjk4eC4Hx2' -d "${WKFL_DET}" -o ${V_WF_PARAMS}_new http://someaddress.com/workflows/646
}
func
```

expected output should be :

```
    workflow.log 
"Workparams": [
    {
      "$id": "12",
      "WorkflowParmId": 84232,
      "WorkflowId": 9766,
      "Name": "SYS_FILE_DT",
      "Value": "2018-09-28"
    },
    {
      "$id": "13",
      "WorkflowParmId": 221910,
      "WorkflowId": 9766,
      "Name": "V_FILE_NAME",
      "Value": "ZZZZZZ" ------- from parameter $p_file_name
    },
    {
      "$id": "14",
      "WorkflowParmId": 221908,
      "WorkflowId": 9766,
      "Name": "V_ID",
      "Value": "5555" ----- from parameter $p_id
    }
```

i hope i have explained my problem.

Comment: could you elaborate more on "based on the name"? name of what? the 'Name' property?

Comment: @Xeo28 name of any of the 3 like SYS_FILE_DT,V_FILE_NAME.V_ID .I have given the example of only one.

Comment: Your example isn't clear at all. You want `to compare the old values with new values` but there's no indication in your example of which values are old vs new. Also nowhere in your sample input do you have V_FILE_NAME with BOTH of the values `XXXXXX` and `ZZZZZZ` and I can't even imagine what that would mean or what it is you'd then be setting to `ZZZZZZ`. [edit] your question to show clear sample input and the expected output you'd get given that input.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) you could readily and robustly achieve the transformation as illustrated below:

```
export p_id=5555
export p_file_name=ZZZZZZ

< so-workflow.json jq --arg id "${p_id}" --arg fn "${p_file_name}" '
 .Workparams |= map(if .Name == "V_FILE_NAME"
                    then .Value = $fn 
                    elif .Name == "V_ID" 
                    then .Value = $id 
                    else . end)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should use JSON parser tools like jg for such cases. A brute force attack for the particular problem using Perl is below. Check this out:

```
> export p_id=5555
> export p_file=ZZZZZZ
> perl -pe '$x++ if /V_FILE_NAME/;$y++ if /V_ID/;s/XXXXXX/$ENV{p_file}/ if $x and /Value/ and $x--;s/1111/$ENV{p_id}/ if $y and /Value/ and $y--' workflow.log
"Workparams": [
        {
          "$id": "12",
          "WorkflowParmId": 84232,
          "WorkflowId": 9766,
          "Name": "SYS_FILE_DT",
          "Value": "2018-09-28"
        },
        {
          "$id": "13",
          "WorkflowParmId": 221910,
          "WorkflowId": 9766,
          "Name": "V_FILE_NAME",
          "Value": "ZZZZZZ"
        },
        {
          "$id": "14",
          "WorkflowParmId": 221908,
          "WorkflowId": 9766,
          "Name": "V_ID",
          "Value": "5555"
        }
]

>
```